# Garage Door Opener Damaged by HF RF?

Tags: hf, rfi

Yeah, this is a crazy one.

My wife's garage door opener stopped working yesterday. I replaced the battery and it works when very close to the garage door receiver, like underneath.

Today, my son tells me his garage door opener isn't working. His is 2 weeks old and opens a different door (not the same as my wife). It works when you elevate it to the window and a few feet from the receiver.

So I tested mine, the same door as my son, and it took has a extremely limited range. I could not open the door unless I held the opener up high @ the window.

Previously, we could open the door at the top of the driveway, at least 30 feet away. Now, unless it is in line-of-sight with the receiver, the receiver doesn't receive.

The only thing different is my operating an end-fed @ 100 watts on 40 meters. Prior to my operating @ 40 meters, the garage door receiver had a decent +30 foot range. Now, it's practically deaf.

The low receive occurs when not transmitting, like tonight, when we went out to eat. This is when my son told me his door opener doesn't work.

So ... did my amateur radio operation permanently damage the garage door receivers?

**12/16/22 update:**

The garage doors openers are back to normal, operating properly as they did before. As quickly as the receivers went deaf, they can hear again. I never did find the source of the problem.

Using my RTL-SDR and tuning from 300-400 MHz, I found them @ 309.5 MHz. I was expecting to see something else on the waterfall but the only signal present was the door opener transmitter. Not much noise at all from 300-400 MHz actually.

The dead Vizio soundbar ... that too did not emit any noise (that I could see) from 300-400 MHz. I expected it was the culprit by the test proved otherwise.

The neighbors to the immediate left and right of me did not have any garage door problems while mine was acting-up. So the problem was isolated to my house. Again, nothing new in the house, the same bulbs, electronics, and everything.

I am glad that they are back to an operational state and still wonder what the root cause of the problem was.

Comment: Has the antenna on the garage door been modified, lengthened, or was it touching something metal?

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly possible. Equipment is *supposed* to be designed not to be damaged by exposure to reasonable amounts of RF on unrelated frequencies, 100W is *usually* a low enough power that it doesn't bother anything more than a few feet from the antenna, and 40m is so far away from the frequencies that garage door openers use that it's *usually* thoroughly filtered. But bad luck, and bad design, do happen, and sometimes receivers do end up fried in exactly the way you described.

If that's what happened, some things that you can do, besides replacing the dead receivers:

1. Don't play radio, or run less power. Yeah, I know, not much fun.
2. Relocate the antenna further away from the victim.
3. Replace the garage door openers with a different model and hope that the new ones aren't susceptible in the same way.
4. Try to put up a different kind of antenna. End-feds almost inevitably start right next to the house, and they almost inevitably have common-mode problems. Both of those mean that they tend to couple a fair amount of RF power into your house's electrical wiring, and that makes it more likely that you will bzzt some equipment.

But, it's also possible that it's just a coincidence, that your garage door openers aren't damaged at all, and that there's some interference source nearby that showed up in the past few days that's drowning out the signal from the remotes. You might want to investigate that, maybe using a laptop with a cheap SDR receiver tuned to the frequency your openers use (which will either be found on the label or in the manual, or found by searching for the FCC ID printed on the label or in the manual).

Comment: It's likely a coincidence, IMHO. *Unless* the RF damaged the opener via the AC power lines or button wiring.

Answer (score 0):

I have not replaced anything in the house for a while, no new electronics, nothing new at all.

This is very strange. I understand that some devices may act-up when transmitting, but my two door openers are practically deaf now. I bought new batteries today and the door won't open unless the remote opener is a few feet from the receiver. The wire buttons of course open/close the door perfectly.

Last night when we returned home, the garage door bulbs were off, the garage was dark, and it still wouldn't open - I waived the remote around in the air with the button pressed and it eventually opened.

On a perhaps related note, my Vizio soundbar mysteriously died Friday night while watching a movie. It is dead. I opened it and didn't see any blown/bulging capacitors. Googling the problem, I see many others have similar problems with the Vizio soundbars crapping out after a few years. It is coincidental that the garage door openers and soundbar are both affected the same day.

I was not transmitting when the soundbar died - the radio was off and we were watching a movie.

As I lead-off, very strange.

Could the front-end of the garage door receiver be damaged? I presume it either works or doesn't work. It doesn't make sense that it works but only when the opener is a few feet from the receiver.

Comment: Rather than posting this additional information as an answer, it should have been added to [your question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/21527/8717). I started to do this for you, but my tablet was acting strange and I finally gave up.

Comment: Echoing Mike, mind updating your question to include this info? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd also consider that one of your neighbors just bought some sort of equipment that is transmitting on the same frequency as your door opener. Maybe something as simple as a cheap switching power supply that kicks out a ton of harmonics. I put my opener on a spectrum analyzer and it was somewhere around 700 MHz as I recall.  If you know anybody with a spectrum analyzer have him/her come by and do a little snooping.

Comment: You can find out the frequency of a transmitter by looking up the FCC id of the device.  In the US, at least, they are required to file the technical specs, which are verified by the FCC and published.  This can help you know where you should be listening and could help you to investigate without a spectrum analyzer provided you have something that can tune the frequency in question.

Answer (score 0):

End fed antennas have high voltage at the feed point. That is usually near your house. if the match and/or balun aren’t right 100-5,000 Volts of RF is looking for ground outside the antenna. It sounds like it burned out what ever serves as what used up be called the ‘front end’ of the garage door opener recover. Adding a counterpoise to the open side of you feed line, improving your antenna  match and bualn at the feed point, moving the feed point away from the house, chancing the antenna to one fed off center fed, and/or build 40 & 15 meter notch filters for each of the third set new garage door openers.

As you apply those remedies at some point the garage doors should stop failing or you will trash the antenna as many of us have rather put up with the QRN, RFI need for new garage door opener receivers.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so I wrote an answer.

Just two more possibilities: you don't need to have a powerful signal on the receiving frequency of a radio or near to it to prevent its receiver working. Two or more strong signals at the same time on very different frequencies may cause your radio to not receiving as well. They just mix up somehow in the receiving circuits. We experienced this as stable phenomenons on V/UHF repeater towers until the problems were eliminated by changing a repeater frequency, or by changing the receiver (maybe, these happened two-three decades ago).

The other one: hadn't been the temperature outside changing wildly in this week? :-)